# Can't get sessionstorage object key

Tags: javascript

I have an object stored in my sessionstorage looking like:

```
{"primaryColor":"#0D9FD0","secondaryColor":"#0FD64D"}
```

But when I want to get the primaryColor and secondaryColor, I get undefined?
Can't quite spot why I get this?

the code:

```
const colorsFromStorage = sessionStorage.getItem("defaultColors");
const parsedColors = JSON.parse(colorsFromStorage);
console.log(parsedColors); //Return the object
console.log(parsedColors.primaryColor); //returns undefined?????
```

Comment: some other issue

Comment: `//Return the object` Can you share exactly what is returned? Also share the output of `console.log(Object.keys(parsedColors));`

Comment: Just a hunch but could the issue be in how it's actually set in session storage? This seems to work just fine:
`sessionStorage.setItem("defaultColors", "{\"primaryColor\" : \"#0D9FD0\",\"secondaryColor\" : \"#0FD64D\"}")`